# Calculating effect sizes when a certain proportion of subjects give one of four answers

Tags: effect-size, frequency

How can an effect size be calculated between two groups when the data is reported in frequency proportions (e.g., each group has people who have answered a question about relationships with either: very close, quite close, not very close or not close at all)?  Is using the frequency proportion effect size calculator the answer?

Comment: According to wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size, there are different kinds of effect size. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

An indicator of effect size need not express every detail inherent in the data.  For example, you might want to designate as your effect size the difference between Group A and Group B in the percentage of people who answered at least "quite close."  Or in the percentage who gave any answer except "not close at all."  If a test of statistical significance is desired, you could test such a result using either a chi-square test of independence or a test of the difference between proportions.